# Humans in a world without trees

Tags: science-fiction, scientific-development

How do you think humans would develop technologically in a world without trees? If all the other requirements of basic survival like food, oxygen, etc are met? There are animals around but no cellulose producing stationary lifeforms. Oxygen-cycle is maintained by some other mechanism. Main "Herbivores" would derive thier energy by "camping" near radioactive rocks and licking them. These are hunted by other animals and humans who in this world are a lot more resistant to ionizing radiation(though animals will wait for the radioactive substance to decay to a safe level before consuming). As for radioactive substance think of a small half-life, alpha emitter.

Comment: Oxygen cycle is currently mostly maintained by the plants in the sea if I understand the research enough. So that is one concern less.

Comment: @Trioxidane It is maintained by some other process. Say the planet or world has mineral that decay to oxygen at a steady state.

Comment: Well, you've told us what there isn't, can you edit to tell us what there is if there are no plants. What is the basis of the ecosystem? How is life without plants finding food?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Just updated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a [High Concept Question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/is-it-possible-and-reasonable-to-add-this-is-a-high-concept-question-to-the-li). As written, the query is open ended and likely to generate varied opinions more than focused answers.

Comment: Plants are the base of almost every food chain that isn't located in a place without light. You're not just asking for how we'd fare without plants, you're basically asking about entirely new form of alien ecosystems that evolved without relying on photosynthesis for introduction of new organic matter into the system. These do exist in fact, in the bottom of the ocean, where the smartest things around are octopuses. Your world might be more believable if the base of the food chain is something closer to the radiation eating fungi like we've seen in Chernobyl rather than "Kaiju" animals.

Comment: Also, if your animals feed directly on radiation, chances are that they don't need to be big, or very mobile. In fact if there are ample sources of radiation they don't need to be more than fungi (and I don't expect them to become more than fungi either), especially since an animal the size of a cow that functions like one needs **a lot** more energy to survive than a mushroom that has fraction of its size and metabolic rate.

Comment: I suspect that without cellulose, there would be something LIKE cellulose coming from the primary energy harvesters or there wouldn't be enough structure to support a complex ecosystem. No trees is doable, no cellulose is a tough sell.

Comment: This is high concept but I am digging high concept.  For your world - remember creatures need fuel for the fire but also material to build bodies with.  Plant material serves double duty for animalia but other organisms (eg bacteria) split energy intake and anabolism into separate categories.  Your rock lickers still need something to build bodies from.  Maybe air?  Maybe ask another question?  Just thinking.

Comment: I agree with @elemtilas that this is a HCQ. We can look to what ancient cultures here on Earth that lived in wood-limited conditions did - but that can't answer the much too broad question "How do you think humans would develop technologically in a world without trees?" because no human civilization that still exists today did so without the influence of trees eventually. And a legitimate argument could be made that technologically there would be no difference (eventually) since no critical technology today depends on trees... and that's just an opinion, too.

Comment: Those people would not be able to properly celebrate Christmas.

Comment: Downvoted because it's not even wrong in so many different ways.  E.g. there aren't enough radioactive rocks to live on, there are large areas of basically treeless grasslands that are quite productive, humans descended from tree-dwelling primates, so there wouldn't BE humans without trees...

Answer (score 3):

**Like the Inuit or Mongolian tribes**

So assuming no trees and vegetation all you have to work with are rocks, minerals and animal stuff. This seems a lot like how the Inuit live where this is relatively the case or somewhat less how Mongolian tribes lived on the steppes.

I don't know how far up the technology tree you are looking at so I will make a start.

1. The first "technology to evolve would be making bone speers and clothing.
2. Afterwards stone cutting to reinforce speers and other tools and tents, clothing and such.
3. If viable, animal domestication would probably come next (could be switched with 4)
4. A next step would probably be fire from dried animal dung and/or animal fat

Now any further steps become situational I think. But in a good location you might expect the following.

5. Finding that coal can be used as fuel
6. Figuring out the you can melt copper and use it as a material.
   (This is the step which is most unsure, but of which I also don't know how our
   ancestors have managed it. They may even have an edge since they would be more used
   to work with stones and presumably crystals or other minerals)
7. From there slowly evolve further.

Although not having wood is most definitely a down side, I don't think the lack of it breaks any chance of developing technology.

**EDIT / ADDITIONAL THOUGHTS**

I just remembered that coal is mostly dead plant matter (duh!). Maybe dead algae or enough dead animals also produce coal or burnable oil. But probably your world will be in a short supply of fossil fuels, which will make smelting more difficult. You could burn some metals but it might be tricky to get started or envision a stable geo-active planets where you have access to magma?

Comment: Recent studies have called into question the fossil fuel theory of hydrocarbon fuels.  The other theory is that most if not all hydrocarbon fuels are naturally occurring inorganic substances. https://deepcarbon.net/feature/hydrocarbons-form-surprisingly-high-earth

Comment: Yeah, and without cellulose in the food chain, there would be no burnable animal dung. It's a tough question and pretty unrealistic.

Comment: @Nosajimiki - The definition of organic is contains carbon, so “inorganic hydrocarbons” is self-contradictory. Also, your included link has a failing certificate, so I can’t look to see if the inorganic is a misstatement or what the study suggests.

Comment: @EricG The definition of "organic chemical compound" is that it contains carbon bonded with certain other elements such as hydrogen.   Inorganic in this context just means something not originating from an organism.

Comment: The link got truncated.  Here: http://deepcarbon.net/feature/hydrocarbons-form-surprisingly-high-earth%25E2%2580%2599s-mantle

Comment: @Nosajimiki: "Recent studies" funded by global warming deniers, perhaps?  One might note the abundance of fossil plants in coal beds: https://www.sciencebuzz.org/blog/huge-underground-fossil-rainforests-discovered-illinois-coa

Comment: You still need to chose a word other than “inorganic” if you are trying to use that description in a scientific context, especially without any context of what the supposed compounds are. 

From a security perspective, there is no justification for visiting a site with an invalid certificate. Who knows what other security failures I would be subjecting myself to if they can’t keep track of absolute basics?

Comment: @jamesqf Maybe... or maybe not.  deepcarbon was funded by the Alfred P. Sloan Foundation.  Nothing on either of their websites seem to specifically advocate anything of the sort, but part of the the reasoning behind the theory of oil originating in the mantel has to do with how oil is distributed in the crust with very large oil fields being over 6 miles deep (over 2 miles deeper than the deepest fossils ever found.)

Comment: Considering we can’t get more than a bore hole 6 miles deep, it’s not surprising that we haven’t found fossils at that depth.

Comment: @EricG Then, let's go with Abiogenic meaning: not produced or brought about by living organisms; of inorganic origin.

Comment: @jamesqf The theory is certainly controversial, but there is enough evidence to at least  support it as a possibility for world building purposes.  I've found the wikipedia page on it covering both reasons why people support and deny the theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenic_petroleum_origin

Comment: Abiotic. That is probably the actual word you should use if you don’t want to have frustrating conversations like this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think humans would evolve at all in a world with no trees.

According to the general agreement on the evolution of hominids, what later became homo sapiens started developing as they were forced to abandon the trees because of an environment turning more and more savanna-like, with scarce trees.

If trees never existed in the first place, that path would have never been taken, so what we today know as humans would have not come to be.

Comment: If they evolve, then what? Say they were teleported from earth to some other planet. This planet is very similar to earth but does not have any trees.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible currently, but maybe in the coming decades it is possible with technology and human ideas. We are now trying to make lives on planets other than the Earth such as mars, the moon, etc. So the tech we are using to make life possible there, the same equipment can be used to live without trees on the Earth.

Comment: Thank you for coming to Worldbuilding stack exchange and trying to answer this question. Please check out the [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help)for advice on how to write a better answer. Also, please check out [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) about saying thanks or other taglines (such as “hope it will help”) in your posts.